Logging in from new sign up C# console app
I am enrolled in a Software Engineering program and am working on my 2nd assignment, so still very new. I have some issues with figuring out how to login with my new signup information and not sure how to go about it.
I'm still fleshing out my signup code to display error messages with whitespace or empty entries, so please don't judge. I have yet to add any comments also.
My main issue is using the new data to then log the user in (I think).
I apologise for the upload of everything if it seems super long, but this is the first time I have used this site to post.
Main program tab:
class BankAccount
{
    public static void MainMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Bam's Bank of NSW. \nPlease select from the following menu: \n1: Login \n2: Sign up \n3: Quit");

        int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                Login();
                break;

            case 2:
                SignUp();
                break;

            case 3:
                Program.Quit();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void WelcomeMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome John \nPlease select from the following menu: \n1: View Balance \n2: Deposit \n3: Withdraw \n4: Transfer \n5: Quit");

        int input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (input1)
        {
            case 1:
                Bank.ViewBalance();
                break;

            case 2:
                Bank.Deposit();
                break;

            case 3:
                Bank.Withdraw();
                break;

            case 4:
                Bank.Transfer();
                break;

            case 5:
                Program.Quit();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void SignUp()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing Bam bank of NSW.\nPlease enter your details to open a new account\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");

        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Email. This will become your Username:");

        string email = Console.ReadLine();

        if (email == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot be blank.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Age:");
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (age < 18)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("To open an account you need to be 18yrs.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please create a password:");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (password == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot be blank.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Account successfully created for {email}. Please login");

        Accounts accounts = new Accounts();
        accounts.Name = name;
        accounts.Email = email;
        accounts.Age = age;
        accounts.Password = password;
        Accounts.AllAccounts.Add(accounts);

        Console.ReadKey();
        Login();
    }

    public static void Login()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your email/username");

        string uname = Console.ReadLine();
        Accounts accounts = new Accounts();

        if (uname == accounts.Email)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Password");
        }
        else if (uname != accounts.Email)
        {
            TryAgain();
        }

        string pword = Console.ReadLine();

        if (pword == accounts.Password)
        {
            WelcomeMenu();
        }
        else if (pword != accounts.Password)
        {
            TryAgain();
        }
    }

    public static void TryAgain()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Invalid username/Password. Please select a function.\n1: Try Again \n2: Main Menu \n3: Quit");

        int input2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (input2)
        {
            case 1:
                Login();
                break;

            case 2:
                MainMenu();
                break;

            case 3:
                Program.Quit();
                break;
        }
    }   
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BankAccount.MainMenu();
    }

    public static void Quit()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you and have a nice day! \nPress any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }
}

Accounts tab:
public class Accounts
{
    private static List<Accounts> accounts = new List<Accounts>();

    public static List<Accounts> AllAccounts
    {
        get { return accounts; }
    }
       
    public Accounts()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}       

I have tried a fair few different codes, I found some answers on here and some through learn.microsoft.com, but am not having much luck. If anyone can help me that would be amazing.

I am yet to add any comments: Comments shouldn't be an after-thought - they are something that one adds as one writes the code. They're useful when debugging because it means one doesn't have to re-read every line of code to understand what's happening. However, after one is finished, one may desire to review the comments and modify them as necessary.

The following may be of interest: Debugger documentation - Visual Studio (Windows), Main() and command-line arguments, and Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)

It's unclear whether the account information is meant to persist each time the program is executed. If one runs the program again, should the program be aware of accounts that were created the last time the program was run? If so, then you need to save the information to a file or a database. Keep in mind that passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text which means that if someone seems the password text he/she/they should have no idea what the password is.

You may consider reading the example on the MS website: Explore object oriented programming with classes and objects.

The following may be of interest: static

When writing classes, try to make them as independent as possible. BankAccount shouldn't have any reference to the Program class, for example.

Thank you everyone for your help, I have fixed the problem and am now adding my comments to submit my assignment.

From what I understand you are struggling to implement logging in part.
There you collect data from user (name, password), but you compare all of these agains accounts that was just initialized var accounts = new Accounts();
When object is initialized, all of its fields are empty, so Name and Email will be null and they will fail your login all the time.
You are already storing users' data in Accounts.AllAccounts collection, so you should leverage it. Here is corrected Login method with necessary comments:
public static void Login()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your email/username");

    string uname = Console.ReadLine();
    // Check in all users collection if there's user with given name
    var accounts = Accounts.AllAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == uname);

    if (accounts is null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User with such name not found");
        TryAgain();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Password");
    }

    string pword = Console.ReadLine();
    // Check in all users collection if there's user with given name AND password
    accounts = Accounts.AllAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == uname && x.Password == pword);

    if (accounts is null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong password");
        TryAgain();
    }
    else
    {
        WelcomeMenu();
    }
}


From what you have provided:

You are creating a new instance of the Accounts class, but do not use it in the Login method after the user signs up. Instead you are creating a new instance, which hasn't got any of the data that the user has inputted in.
Instead, you would have to iterate over Accounts.AllAccounts, and find an instance of Accounts which has that username. If they do not, then the account does not exist.
If the account does exist, then check the password they provide with that instance.

There are a couple of other issues with the code:

You use the same switch case statement in MainMenu and TryAgain, perhaps move this to another method to avoid repeating yourself.
The Accounts class should probably be called Account so that it is clear that when you call the constructor, a single account is created.
Your switch cases do not have a default case, so nothing happens if the user does not enter a number which corresponds to one of those cases.

Instead of:
Accounts accounts = new Accounts();
accounts.Name = name;
accounts.Email = email;
accounts.Age = age;
accounts.Password = password;

You could do
var accounts = new Accounts
{
    Name = name,
    Email = email,
    Age = age,
    Password = password
};

Apart from that, the code looks alright.
Some tips for asking questions on stackoverflow:

Try to provide a minimal, reproducible example. In this case, you haven't provided the Bank class, so someone looking at this code cannot immediately run it.
Be more clear with what you expect your program to do, and what your program actually does.

